# How to prevent mysql connection using hibernate from mysql wait_timeout?

Tags: java, hibernate

I have created one service,that service do some database operations.But that service is IDLE for long time as we don't need that service on regular basis.Let say I did some operation on Monday and after that I want to use that service after 2 days,let say I want to use that service on Wednesday.But as mysql has one property **wait_timeout** mysql closes my connection after its **wait_timeout** defined value.
Is there any hibenate configuration property which will automatically reconnect to the database **after wait_timeout is over**.
I have searched several options : 
1] Add autoReconnect true in hibernate configuration or in database url (Which I already tried but not able to reconnect database after wait_timeout)
2] Use c3p0 connector

Please suggest me the way to reconnect database after wait_timeout.
I haven't used c3p0 connector but I want to know **Is it good to use c3p0,or Is it the best possible solution**

Please let me know any other option in order to reconnect database.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Most connectors provide something like ValidationQuery to prevent loosing the database connection. For mysql the ValidationQuery would be "SELECT 1".

Check [this page](https://confluence.atlassian.com/display/DOC/Surviving+Database+Connection+Closures) for some examples (eg. with c3po, jdbc or directly on datasource). I normally configure the ValidationQuery as part of a DatasourceProvider.